# Is it possible to simplify the coefficient matrix for large values of $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrix-equations, multilinear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

If I have a system of $8$ linear equations for the eight variables $\{\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma ,\delta ,\eta ,\lambda ,\xi ,\rho \}$ and with the three parameters $\{x,y,z\}$ reals and $x>0$. I want to work on nontrivial solutions of the system, therefore, I need to compute the determinant of the coefficient matrix (given below).

**My question:**

> Assuming that the determinant of the coefficient matrix is of a polynomial form in $x$ as $f(x)=c_1 x^8+c_2 x^7+c_3 x^6+...+c_0$; I need to evaluate the problem only for large values of $x \to \infty$, in other words, I only need to find the coefficient $c_1$. My question is if it is possible to simplify (manipulate) this system of equations (or equivalently, the coefficient matrix) from the beginning for large values of $x$ so that computing the determinant is simpler.

$$  \gamma +\delta +\beta \; e^{\frac{i x}{2}} (x-1)+\delta \; x-\gamma\;  x-\alpha \; e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i x)} (x+1)=0,  \\   \gamma +\delta +x (\gamma +\lambda )-\eta -\lambda -x (\delta +\eta )=0,  $$

$$  \eta  (x-1)+\delta  (x-1) e^{-i (x+y)}-(x+1) \left(\lambda +\gamma  \;e^{i (x-y)}\right)=0, \\\alpha +e^{-\frac{1}{2} i (x+2 y)} \left((x+1) \left(\delta +\beta \; e^{\frac{3 i x}{2}+i y}\right)-\gamma \; e^{2 i x} (x-1)\right)=\alpha \; x,  $$

$$  \rho +\xi\;  e^{2 i x} (x+1)-\rho \; x+\alpha  (x-1) e^{\frac{3 i x}{2}+i y}-\beta  (x+1) e^{\frac{1}{2} i (x+2 y)}=0,\\ \xi \; e^{2 i x} (x-1)-\rho  (x+1)+\eta  (x-1) \left(-e^{i (y+z)}\right)+\lambda  (x+1) e^{i (2 x+y+z)}=0, $$
$$  \xi +\rho +\rho \; x+\lambda  (x-1) e^{i (x+z)}-\xi \; x-\eta  (x+1) e^{-i (x-z)}=0,\\\rho  \;x+\alpha  e^{\frac{i x}{2}} (x+1)-\xi-\rho -\beta \; e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i x)} (x-1)-\xi \; x=0. $$

Coefficient Matrix

$$\scriptsize\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 -e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i x)} (x+1) & e^{\frac{i x}{2}} (x-1) & 1-x & x+1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & x+1 & 1-x & -x-1 & x-1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & (x+1) \left(-e^{i (x-y)}\right) & (x-1) e^{-i (x+y)} & x-1 & -x-1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1-x & e^{i x} (x+1) & (x-1) \left(-e^{\frac{3 i x}{2}-i y}\right) & (x+1) e^{-\frac{1}{2} i (x+2 y)} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 e^{\frac{i x}{2}} (x-1) & -e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i x)} (x+1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (x+1) e^{i (x-y)} & (1-x) e^{-i (x+y)} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (1-x) e^{-i (x-z)} & (x+1) e^{i (x+z)} & (x-1) e^{i (x-y)} & (x+1) \left(-e^{-i (x+y)}\right) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & (x+1) \left(-e^{-i (x-z)}\right) & (x-1) e^{i (x+z)} & 1-x & x+1 \\
 e^{\frac{i x}{2}} (x+1) & -e^{-\frac{1}{2} (i x)} (x-1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -x-1 & x-1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

P.S. I have already asked this in MathStackExchange but did not receive any answers. Any comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $M:=M(x,y,z)$ be the $8\times8$ matrix in question. Let $m(x):=M(x,0,0)$.

We have
$$\det m(x)=
-256 e^{i x/2} x^2 \cos (2 x) \big((x^2+1)^2 \cos (2 x)-(x^2-1)^2\big).$$

So, $|\det m(x)|$ will be oscillating between the value $0$ (attained when $\cos (2 x)=0$ -- that is, when $x=(2k-1)\pi/4$ for natural $k$) and the value $512 x^2 (1 + x^4)\sim512 x^6$ (attained when $\cos (2 x)=-1$ -- that is, when $x=(2k-1)\pi/2$ for natural $k$). The value $0$ will also be taken by $\det m(x)$ at the occurring almost periodically roots of the equation $\cos (2 x)=r(x):=\dfrac{(x^2-1)^2}{(x^2+1)^2}$, as $r(x)$ is strictly increasing from $0$ to $1$ for $x$ increasing from $1$ to $\infty$, whereas $\cos (2 x)$ is periodically oscillating between $-1$ and $1$.

In general,
$$\det M(x,y,z)=32 x^2 e^{i (x-4 y+2 z)/2} \\ 
\times\big(-4 (x^2-1)^2 \sin ^2(x) [\cos (2 y)+\cos (z)] \\ 
+4 (x^2-1)^2 \cos (2 x)-4 (x^2+1)^2 \cos (4 x)-16 x^2\big).$$
So, by the triangle inequality,
$$|\det M(x,y,z)|\le32 x^2 \\ 
\times\big(4 (x^2-1)^2 \times2 \\ 
+4 (x^2-1)^2+4 (x^2+1)^2+16 x^2\big)=512 x^2 (1 + x^4).$$

Thus,

> $|\det M(x,y,z)|\le512 x^2 (1 + x^4)$ for all $x,y,z$, whereas $|\det M(x,0,0)|$ will be oscillating between $0$ and $512 x^2 (1 + x^4)\sim512 x^6$.

In particular, it follows that your assumption

> Assuming that the determinant of the coefficient matrix is of a polynomial form in $x$ as $f(x)=c_1 x^8+c_2 x^7+c_3 x^6+...+c_0$; I need to evaluate the problem only for large values of $x \to \infty$, in other words, I only need to find the coefficient $c_1$.

is quite counterfactual.

---

Here are the calculations, done in Mathematica (click on the image below to magnify it):

[image]

Comment: @charmin : Your comments paint a picture quite different from that described in your post. It appears from your comments that you have -- not just one specific $8\times8$ matrix as in your post -- but a number of matrices, including an $88\times88$ one. The question as it was stated in your post has been fully answered (with the erroneous assumption in your post now corrected).

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, I suggest you finalize the current question and then post another question, about the set of matrices of your actual interest, including the $88\times88$ one, and then it would be helpful to know how those matrices were produced. Also, concerning your latest comment, it is unclear what you mean by "polynomial function **for** determinant"; it is shown in my answer that neither the determinant nor its modulus is a polynomial function (even though the modulus of the determinant is bounded by a polynomial function).

Comment: @charmin : The answer gives a simple, easy to analyze expression for the determinant. Your question was about the main-term asymptotics coefficient $c_1$ of the determinant. The answer, in particular, shows that $c_1$ is actually, not a constant, but with the modulus oscillating between $0$ and $512$. Also, your exponent $8$ of  $x^8$ was corrected in the answer to the actual exponent $6$. So, your question, as stated, was fully answered.

Comment: Previous comment continued: As for "simplifying my matrix for large values of $x$", I cannot attach any specific meaning to that. All the entries of the matrix seem already to be in their simplest form.

Comment: Also, it is unclear what the purpose of your question was. To solve a system of linear equations, one is usually not concerned with large values of the determinant of the system. Rather, one is usually concerned with small values of the determinant and especially, with the zero value of it. It is shown in the answer that your determinant is $0$ for certain however large values of $x$. In such cases, your system may have no solutions or infinitely many solutions.

Comment: As for "simplifying my matrix for large values of $x$", I mean if it is possible to remove those terms in matrix which does not play a role in the coefficient $c_1$.

Comment: @charmin : "remove those terms in matrix which does not play a role in the coefficient $c_1$"?? You can remove such a set of entries of the matrix if the sum of the contributions of their cofactors is negligible. So, to find such a nontrial set of entries (in the unlikely case when it exists at all!), one would have to examine asymptotically for large $x$ the contributions of the cofactors of the $32$ nonzero entries of the matrix and then the sums of about $2^{32}$ subsets of the set of the contributions of those $32$ cofactors.

Comment: Previous comment continued: This is for the $8\times8$ matrix. Now it is scary to think of the $88\times88$ case. Is this your idea of simplification?

Comment: Thanks! So, the answer to my question is that "No, it is not possible", right?

Comment: @charmin : the answer to the question about such a simplification is that (i) such a simplification is unlikely to exist at all and (ii) even if such a simplification exists, it will be incomparably harder to find than to just deal with the determinant directly. Also, as I wrote, I think you should be concerned, not with large values of the determinant, but with its small values (when solutions may explode to $\infty$ in modulus) and with its zero values, when solutions may not exist at all (or when there may be infinitely many of them).

Comment: I am not a mathematician and I simply thought maybe it is possible for example to replace $x+1$ by $x$ in each entry but it gives the wrong result.